# winform + wpf Focus Issue (click event does not fire for wpf)

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have WPF control hosted in win form. In the upper part of the window I have winform control (grid) and below the grid I have placed my WPF control.The wpf control has list of records and for each record there is a hyperlink provided to delete or edit. when the focus is on the grid and try to click on wpf hyperlink, the hyperlink click event does not fire instead it sets the focus on the wpf control. And in the next click it calls the hyperlink event. I want to avoid these two clicks. It should fire the click event in the first shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method "protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)"
you could capture the element in this method.
If the captured element is Hyperlink, then you could fire the click event of that Hyperlink.

I hope this works ;)

Comment: Did it fire in the first shot!! ;)